# Using AAD for client auth still requires cert

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've created a new cluster with AAD for client auth using ARM by following the document linked to below. The cluster deployed and my app works fine but my browser is still asking me to select an X.509 certificate when I attempt to use the SF Explorer at: https://mycluster.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Explorer

I thought when I hooked up Azure AD that the client cert would no longer be needed. Note that I do see that the SF Explorer displays my name in the upper right (with a logout option), indicating to me it's using AAD.

So, what's up with this? Any ideas?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens if there's an issue with AAD authentication - the cluster will fallback to certificate authentication.

If SF Explorer isn't re-directing to an AAD login page at all, then double-check that the web application reply URL in the AAD cluster application matches the SF Explorer URL.

If the re-direction is happening and AAD login was successful, then double-check that the AAD cluster application has the expected user roles and that your user has been assigned a role.

Comment: Alex, SF explorer is not re-directing to the AAD login page. I have triple checked that my SF explorer URL matches what is setup in AAD. No idea what's wrong.

Comment: Ahh, I finally figured it out. The page in the old Azure Portal where you assign users to an application has an "Assigned" column. That column showed "Yes" for my username but when I highlighted it the "Assign" option lit up. Turns out I was NOT ASSIGNed to that app even though the Portal said Yes. Grumble, Grumble, Grumble. I wasted 3-4 hours on this and looked at those settings a dozen times.